# Break the sentence in equation using underbrace

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, amsmath

I am using underbrace in my equation to describe the content, but it's showing up with a lot of gap

[image]

```
\begin{equation} \small
\begin{small}
    \tiny Loss_{total}=\underbrace{\textstyle(1-\alpha)\; \footnotesize Loss_{ce}}%
    _{\text{ \tiny first Embedding \newline Loss}}+ \underbrace{\textstyle(1-\alpha)\; \footnotesize Loss_{se}}%
    _{\text{ \tiny second Embedding \newline loss}}
\end{small}
\end{equation}
```

I changed the all fonts to footernotesize and tiny but still it's too large in one column of latex page. How to make it small to fit better in one page?

How to break the sentence "first Embedding loss"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my MWE and it is a one of more possible solutions. I will make your code in this manner using `\substack` command on two lines + `\\`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathit{Loss}_{\text{total}}= \underbrace{(1-\alpha)\mathit{Loss}_{\text{ce}}}_{\substack{\text{first Embedding} \\ \text{loss}}}+\underbrace{(1-\alpha)\mathit{Loss}_{\text{se}}}_{\substack{\text{second Embedding} \\ \text{loss}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I add another version on correct suggestion of the user **@Not A Zoomed Image**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\textup{Loss}_{\textup{total}}= \underbrace{(1-\alpha)\textup{Loss}_{\textup{ce}}}_{\substack{\text{first Embedding} \\ \textup{loss}}}+\underbrace{(1-\alpha)\textup{Loss}_{\textup{se}}}_{\substack{\textup{second Embedding} \\ \textup{loss}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Loss` should be wrapped with `\text` rather than `\mathit` unless `Loss` is the product of `L`, `o`, `s`, and `s`. :-)

Comment: @NotAZoomedImage Surely :-) but I have seen a incomplete MWE of the user without command. Now I add your suggestion. I always use or `\textup` or `\text` or `\mathrm`.

Comment: +1: ............